# Swift get inner classes list

Tags: swift, reflection

Is there any way to get list of inner classes in Swift?

In other words: Does swift has Java analog of `.class.getClasses()`?

Comment: It may be done with objc/runtime.h. look the original objc source file. You may find something. https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/master/runtime/objc-class.mm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift nested class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806932/swift-nested-class-properties)