# Creating namespaces with classes in Swift

Tags: swift

I am a newb to Swift, I am looking to create some nested namespaces, like so:

```
import Foundation 

public class Foo {
    class Moo {
        class Bar{}
    }
}
```

and then I can do:

```
var f = Foo.Moo.Bar()
```

do we not need to use the static keyword here? I don't understand why I don't need to do it like so:

```
import Foundation 

public class Foo {
    static class Moo {
        static class Bar{}
    }
}

var f = Foo.Moo.Bar()
```

can anyone explain why?

Comment: I suspect you come from Java. If so, please see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26807041/77567) helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foo.Moo.Bar` is just the name of the class. You're not accessing a particular instance of `Foo` or `Moo` when you do this:

```
var f = Foo.Moo.Bar()
```

You're just creating an instance of the `Foo.Moo.Bar` class.

Comment: See also https://medium.com/@johnsundell/namespacing-swift-code-with-nested-types-10eabddaa97d

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone explain why?

Can you explain why *not?* What would a `static class` even mean? How can a *class* be *static?* Maybe you come from a language where that keyword means something special in this context?

In any case, in Swift it wouldn't mean anything. The word `static` has just one very simple meaning in Swift: A type *member*, i.e. a property (`var` or `let`) or method (`func`) is either an instance member or a type member; to distinguish the latter case, we say `static` (or `class`). This is neither of those. It is, as you rightly say, merely a namespaced type.